# MS SQL server user account for ODBC access

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, public

I am trying to create a user account in SQL Server 2008 R2 to use for ODBC access restricted to one database. I am unable to create an account with a valid password. How can I give public, read-only access to the database using the ODBC driver. The users have no admin privileges on our network so NT authority wont work. Any Ideas??

Thanks,

Jhmpro

Answer (score 0):

1.create a new login sql server.

2.in login properties goto User Mapping.

3.Tick the desired database in the upper pane and

4.Tick access levels in lower pane:

- tick db_datareader if you need readonly access
- tick db_datareader and db_datawriter if you need write access in lower pane.

5.Link your tables to SQL Server with this login.